# Why doesn't this replace() replace "my"?

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone explain why the replace() below doesn't replace "my"

```
$(function() {
  var str = "put image in my gallery";
  str = str.replace(/ my | in /g, " ");
});
```

There's a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kxjEE/).

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is because of the spaces that you omit

Comment: I think the cause is you're using " in " (including its space), so "my" doesn't have a space before it (replaces are done at the same time). You could use regexp or, simply, using `str = str.replace(" in ", " ").replace(" my ", " ");`, that way you'll replace " my " using the space generated in the first replace (changing " in " to " "). This should be simpler, because there are only two terms to replace (you could concatenate more, of course), but this should avoid complex regexp for simple replaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using:

```
str.replace(/\bmy\b|\bin\b/g, "");
```

Your method also replaces the spaces around the words, which is why the second one isn't replaced.

Edited to add a solution for lots of words:

```
$(function() {
  var toReplace = ['what','a','lot','of','words'];
  var r = '';
    toReplace.forEach(function(v) {
        r += '\\b' + v + '\\b|';
    });
    r.substring(0, r.length - 1); // remove the final '|'
    var re = new RegExp(r,"g");
  var str = "here are some words";
  str = str.replace(re, "");
    console.log(str);
});
```

All you have to do is put the words into the array. http://jsfiddle.net/kxjEE/7/

Comment: @alfasin it works, you just forgot to assign it back. http://jsfiddle.net/kxjEE/4/ +1 for the working answer.

Comment: I meant that it leaves 2 spaces as a "gap" in the result: http://jsfiddle.net/kxjEE/5/

Comment: @alfasin Oh yes you're right there. I was going to fix that (posting another alternative on my answer) but then I realized it could be broken by punctuation so yeah.

Comment: This seems to the best solution since it finds the words at the beginning and end, where they're not bracketed by spaces. It's just that is soooo ugly. It's hard to tell at a glance that "in" and "my" are being replaced. In the actual application there are about 30 words to find and replace, so it will be even  harder there to see if a particular word is in the list. But it does work.  Thanks.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your question! See my edit.

Comment: @Grim The addition of the array is nice!  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Because the matcher has already advanced. The matches cannot overlap, so the space after `in` cannot be used to match the space before `my`.

Here's the rundown, with `|` representing the position of the matcher:

```
'put image| in my gallery' //found the first space
'put image| in |my gallery' //completed a match
'put image |my gallery' //replaced the match with a " "
'put image |my gallery' //fails to match the required space before "my"
```

---

Workarounds include doing 2 runs (executing `.replace()` twice as in @alfasin's answer), or use the `\b` anchor to match at word boundaries instead of spaces (@Grim's solution).

Here's my alternative solution with a single replace operation (assumes a trailing space after the matched words):

```
'put image in my gallery'.replace(/\b(?:my|in) /g, '');
//'put image gallery'
```

`\b` is a zero-width assertion, that is, it matches between word characters (`\w`) and non-word characters (`\W`), this way the matches won't overlap and there's no extra spaces after the replacements have been performed. Of course, this is just to give you an idea, specific use cases (e.g. involving punctuation) will require more specialized regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to:

```
$(function() {
     var str = "put image in my gallery";
        str = str.replace(/ my( |\,|\.|\?)/g, " ").replace(/ in( |\,|\.|\?)/g, " ");
    console.log(str);
});
```

Comment: The brackets around the words are redundant.

Comment: +1 for the working solution, should work as long as long as the words have leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté good point! if there's a "." or "," after one of the words it won't work - these cases needs to be handled. I expanded the answer to include additional cases, but probably there are others...

Comment: @alfasin well you know, punctuation is kinda off-topic to the question, I just tend to get carried away too much. `:P` Don't let my comments waste your time lol.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement of " in " to " " modifies the space before "my", so the space before it is already considered as processed and the replacement continues right after the space.

Try the string "put image in my my gallery", the first one will be left as is while the second one will be replaced.

Others have already answered how to reach the wanted result, so this is just an explanation to the ***why***.